# Shared memory with array of structs

Tags: c, ipc, shared-memory

I'm using an array of structs for share data between two process. The program after 3 secs raise an `Segmentation fault` error, when I try to access to the shared memory into the parent process. Why the data is not correctly shared?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

#define LEN     3

typedef struct {
    int val;
} val_t;

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    key_t   key;
    int     shmid, i, size;
    val_t   **val;

    if ((key = ftok(argv[0], 'D')) == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(1);
    }

    size = sizeof(val_t *) * LEN;

    if (fork() == 0) {
        if ((shmid = shmget(key, size, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666)) == -1) {
            perror("shmget");
            exit(1);
        }

        val = (val_t **) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        if (val == (val_t **)(-1)) {
            perror("shmat");
            exit(1);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
            val[i] = (val_t *) malloc(sizeof(val_t));
            val[i]->val = i;
        }

        while (val[0]->val != 3)
            sleep(1);

        if (shmdt(val) == -1) {
            perror("shmdt");
            exit(1);
        }
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    }
    else {
        sleep(3);

         if ((shmid = shmget(key, size, IPC_EXCL)) == -1) {
            perror("shmget");
            exit(1);
        }

        val = (val_t **) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        if (val == (val_t **)(-1)) {
            perror("shmat");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("%d\n", val[0]->val);
        val[0]->val = 3;

        if (shmdt(val) == -1) {
            perror("shmdt");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) There is no "array of `struct`". You have a pointer to pointer to `struct`, but likely want a "pointer to `struct`" according to your title. 2) Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. 3) Not sure, but if `val` is the shared array, why do you set the pointers to "private" memory? 4) You apparently have problems with the multiple indirection in various places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not sharing an array of structs, you're sharing an array of pointers to structs, and those pointers point into non-shared memory you allocate with malloc.  You want code more like:

```
val_t   *val;
size = sizeof(val_t) * LEN;

if (fork() == 0) {
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, size, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666)) == -1) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1); }

    val = (val_t *) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
    if (val == (val_t *)(-1)) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1); }

    for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        val[i].val = i; }
```

That is, use an array of structs, rather than an array of pointers to structs.

Note that this will only work as long as your structs (and thus your shared memory) *never* have any pointers in them -- even if the pointers were to point at shared memory, it might be at different addresses in the different processes.

Answer (score 1):

You want to share the `struct`s between processes, but instead you are sharing only *pointers* to structs.  If those pointed to `struct`s that were allocated and initialized before the fork then they would be valid in both processes, but would point to different copies of the `struct`s (`malloc()` allocates only private memory, never shared).  As it is, however, the pointers are only valid in the child, which is the one performing the `malloc()`.

So, instead of an array of pointers, allocate an array of structs:

```
val_t *val;

/* ... */

size = sizeof(val_t) * LEN;

/* ... */

val = (val_t *) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
```

If you do it this way, moreover, there is no need to `malloc()` (or `free()`) individual `struct`s.

Comment: Maybe one should add that `malloc` never provides shared memory, but only private.

Comment: Clarified that `malloc()` allocates only private memory.

Answer (score 1):

In,

```
val = (val_t **) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
```

`val` points to an array of type `val_t*` in shared memory. This *can* be accessed in another process that attaches to the same shared memory segment.

But in,

```
val[i] = (val_t *) malloc(sizeof(val_t));
```

`val[i]` points to memory allocated by `malloc()` which is private to a process. This pointer *cannot* be accessed in a different process. Hence the `Segmentation fault` when you do this in the child process.

```
val[0]->val = 3;
```